# Vlookup, Match or Countif - compare 2 UNORDERED columns return differences in third column

Tags: worksheet-function, macbook-pro, vlookup

Macbook Excel.  I need to compare two columns of names, Column A and B to determine which names are in Column A but not in Column B.  Case sensitivity won't work since some names are all caps or mixture in both columns. Also some of the names in Column A do not have middle names and Column B have either middle initial or middle name. So PARTIAL MATCH for let's say last name for example.  I've been trying without success to figure out how to do this using wildcards and syntax with Vlookup.

Comment: You've identified VLOOKUP and MATCH (not sure where COUNTIF would fit in).  What aspect is hanging you up?

Comment: I have 2 columns of names.  I want to compare colA and colB and then in colC list what names do not appear in ColB.  Names in colA are all caps and no middle name.  Names in colB are mixed cases and have middle initials and middle names.

Comment: Been trying to figure out wildcards and syntax with Vlookup.

Comment: Don't worry about an elegant solution. Break the problem down into pieces and deal with each piece. Something this complex won't have a perfect solution, so look for what will cover most of the cases and supplement that with manual verification and cleanup. In A and B, the vast majority of names will have either 1 space (after 1st name), or 2 spaces (also separating a middle name or initial from last name). Use string functions to parse the first and last names based on the spaces and string lengths. (cont'd)

Comment: Convert everything to uppercase and store the cleaned up name string in helper columns for A and B. Then lookup each A helper name in the B helper column.  To verify, sort A and A helper on A helper, and B and B helper on B helper.  You should be able to quickly scan the list visually.  You might even be able to skip the lookup and just skim the columns.